# Postgresql: create an unless-scope-based constraint

Tags: postgresql

For a single table, I need to constrain duplicates of one column outside of the scope of another column.

For example, given a `demographics` table, I would like to enforce that `email` is unique outside of the `person_id`. Add to this exercise that updates to `demographics` records aren't possible via business rules.

Given this data set on the `demographics` table:

```sql
id | email         | city    | person_id |
1  | one@email.com | Buffalo | 100       |
2  | two@email.com | Boston  | 200       |
```

How would I alter `demographics` so that this insert would be ok:

```sql
INSERT INTO demographics (email, city, person_id) VALUES ('one@email.com', 'Miami', '100');
```

But this insert would raise an error:

```sql
INSERT INTO demographics (email, city, person_id) VALUES ('two@email.com', 'Buffalo', '100');
```

?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why the second one should fail, but the first one shouldn't.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The second one adds email `two@email.com` to person `100` while `two@email.com` already belongs to person `200`.

Comment: Looks like a BCNF (or even 4NF) violation to me. Remodelling would cause the {email,city,person_id} to be broken up into two or even three tables.

Comment: Is `email` just plain functionally dependent on `person_id` ? In that case it would be a 2NF violation, solved by putting {person_id -> email} (+UNIQUE email) into a separate table, having an 1:N relation to {person_id, city} (BTW: this is _almost_ identical to the example used by Date, but he did not have email yet)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to implement this constraint I can think of is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that `RAISE EXCEPTION` if the email is already used by another `person_id`. It is not the most eficient way to create a constraint (it requaires a separate `SELECT` on table for every inserted row) but it will definitely work.